# how to write "ah" instead of "al" in interrupt 21 emu8086?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

how can I use `ah` instead of `al` in interrupt 21 in assembly 8086?

Comment: You can't. Int 21h expects a value there. Well, I guess you may create your own interrupt 21h . . . if you dare.

Comment: `mov al, ah`.  Duh.

Answer (score 2):

You mean `int 21h` or `int 21`? The `int 21 (int 15h)` is *"[AT Extended Services / APM](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0212.HTM)"*.

`int 21h (int 33)` is one of [DOS interrupts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS_API).

IIRC emu8086 supports only limited subset of services and interrupts, so I think you meant `int 21h` (and I would expect `int 15h` being unsupported by emu8086).

Pay attention to such typos, it may cause you to debug something for several minutes before you notice the wrong number.

The function of registers when calling `int #n` is defined by the handler, which is installed for that interrupt. The DOS `21h` service has several sub-functions: which one you want to call you define by value in `ah`. This can't be changed, it's hard-wired in the DOS code.

You have to change *your* calling code to prepare the registers as expected by the desired interrupt handler.

(or you can provide your own interrupt handler of course, then you will specify what goes into which register, but creating own interrupt handler doesn't sound like something a user of emu8086 would want to do)

---

Example how to use value from `ah` in "Character output to stdout" service:

```
mov   ah,'X'  ; character value in ah
; how to use it with:
; int 21h, ah=2 (Character output), dl = char (as defined by DOS)
mov   dl,ah   ; move character value into dl (before setting ah with 2)
mov   ah,2    ; number of requested "Character output" service
int   21h     ; call the DOS service
```